# Cluster validation using supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, biostatistics, validation

I have a cancer patient dataset $X_1$ which consists of numerous features and two different sets of labels $y_1$ & $y_2$. I want to show that $y_2$ is a better clustering of patients than $y_1$; the groups that $y_2$ creates are more homogenous.

I also have another dataset $X_2$ which has no overlap in terms of features with $X_1$ but has a strong biological correlation with it. This means that I should be able to use $X_2$ as an external validator for my sets of labels $y_1$ & $y_2$.

Is it valid to fit $X_2$ to a supervised classifier and try to predict $y_1$ or $y_2$ and see which experiment does better in terms of classificatory accuracy? If not, what could be an alternative?